# calculate two consecutive days with XYZ values within a week in a month

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, drupal, joomla

I have a database in MySQL and that have table named `user_daily_data_recorded`. Which have following columns

1. `date_of_record`
2. `steps_walked`
3. `member_id`

The table contains data of each and every date and is populated regularly. Now  I want to send a congratulation mail to user/members `who have walked 15000 steps for at least two  days per week over a month (Say in month February user1 has walked 15000 on Monday and Thursday would receive a congratulatory mail)`. What should I do? Do let me know if my question is not clear.
The file containing this script would be executed only once per month. So i need to find the two  days with 15000 steps per week in a a particular month.

Comment: So you ask how to give notification for user if they reach it after get 15000?

Comment: i know the logic to send mail. just let me know the rest thing i asked

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to select users which should get an e-mail today, this could help:

```
SELECT member_id
FROM   user_daily_data_recorded uddr
       # Selects all users which created a record today.
       JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ( member_id ) AS id
             FROM   user_daily_data_recorded
             WHERE  date_of_record = Curdate()) AS todays_users
         ON todays_users.id = uddr.id
       # Selects all users which where below 15000 steps yesterday.
       JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ( member_id ) AS id
             FROM   user_daily_data_recorded
             WHERE  Sum(steps_walked) < 15000
                    AND date_of_record < Curdate()
             GROUP  BY member_id) AS yesterday_below_mark_users
         ON yesterday_below_mark_users.id = uddr.id
# Selects all members which are over 15000 steps today.
WHERE  Sum(uddr.steps_walked) >= 15000
GROUP  BY member_id
```

I didn't tested it, but may be the steps help you :)

edit: steps over mark by week:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( member_id )
FROM   user_daily_data_recorded uddr
       JOIN (SELECT member_id             AS id,
                    Count(date_of_record) AS dates_over_mark
             FROM   user_daily_data_recorded
             WHERE  Month(date_of_record) = Month(Curdate())
                    AND steps_walked >= 15000
             GROUP  BY Week(date_of_record)
             HAVING dates_over_mark >= 2) AS very_active_members
         ON very_active_members.id = uddr.members_id
```

Comment: thanks for response, but the script you suggested does not use the concept of week.

Comment: The second query should give you the requested users.

Comment: still it is not correct as it gives the two days a week or two that has 15000 steps, but i need the users that has walked 15000 steps for two days per week in complete month for example user1 will be selected if he has walked 15000 steps for 8 days in month(if moth has four week, (two days per week))

Comment: SO you want to select all users, which made more than 15000 steps twice a week and that 4 weeks in a row?

Comment: I want to send mail to that user only who has walked 15000 steps for two days in all the weeks of that month